# Is there a Java Shunting Yard Framework?

Tags: java, framework

I've created several infix to postfix implementations ([shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm)) but find myself starting from scratch each time. I find it reasonable that someone has created a library or framework for this purpose. Sure you could go with full blown compiler techniques but there are a lot of expressions that I find myself wanting to evaluate without such and I find the shunting-yard sufficient.

```
//following is made up code just to illustrate what I'm looking for:
OpperatorGroup opperators = new OpperatorGroup();
opperators.add(
  new Opperator("*",//opperator in string 
                 3,//precedence 
                 LEFT,///associativity for which the direction in multiplication is arbitrary 
                 new CustomLeftAndRightOpperandEvaluator()));//evaluate right and left, or operate on just one side...
  //add a bunch more
Evaluator eval = new Evaluator(opperators);
String result = eval.evaluate(someString);//for which we can assume anything that isn't an opperator is an opperand, and if the string can't be parsed we give up, perhaps with a useful error.
```

Anyways does anyone know of such a shunting-yard framework for Java? I think it would be nice to essentially do a "fill in the blanks" and get a reasonable string evaluator.

**Examples of infix to postfix in past projects**:
One was for a dice roller where 3+7d4*2 would be interpreted as: roll 7 four-sided dice, take their score, multiply by 2 and then add 3. Another implementation was a custom search language, well not so much custom but constrained to allow only the types of operators to act on the Database which I allowed terms such as "Near", "or", "and", etc.

Comment: In principle my "reduced parser" uses such a operator table: https://github.com/axkr/symja-parser/blob/master/symja-parser/src/main/java/org/matheclipse/commons/parser/client/operator/ASTNodeFactory.java but it's not a general framework at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, but what I really need is a framework in Java. Given what you've done I can tell you know what it is that I'm looking for and am a bit surprised that it doesn't exist. I'll put it on my list of things-to-do and self answer... since it isn't a pressing concern perhaps within 6 months.